# cypher query to filter nodes that share a field's values

Tags: cypher

How could I get all nodes that have a shared field value with other nodes, for a specific field?

For example, take the following situation

```
Node ID       Field Value
-------       -----------
   1               a
   2               b
   3               b
   4               c
   5               null
   6               d
   7               d
   8               d
   9               e
```

I'm looking for a query that will return nodes 2,3,6,7,8, because they have repeating field values `b` and `d`. Note I rather *not* `collect` the nodes, but get them as a list.

Comment: If you rather NOT collect nodes, then what is the resulting list? How does it looks like in the return clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is to collect all field values and do a frequency count. Then aggregate the items where the field value count is more than 1. For every item on the list, go back to the nodes where field value is in that items list.

```
MATCH (n:NodeSample) 
\\Get all values for field into a list
WITH collect(n.field) as groupF
\\Use this awesome apoc function to do a frequency count
WITH apoc.coll.frequencies(groupF) as freq
\\This list "items" will have all the field with repeating values
WITH [f in freq where f.count > 1 | f.item] as items
\\Unwind is like a for loop in each item
UNWIND items as item
\\Go find these nodes with that repeating field value
MATCH (m:NodeSample) where m.field = item
\\You can also return just the nodes m; I use the identity id(m) to check my answer
RETURN collect(id(m)) as result

Result:
  [8, 9, 12, 13, 14]
```

Comment: Thank you! the use of `apoc.coll.frequencies` and the filtering of the values is pretty neat

Comment: Glad that you liked it! APOC is awesome and you can also make your own function.  It is another topic :D

Comment: I don't understand the `| f.item` notation. What does it do?

Comment: @JonathanLivni, the result of the apoc function is a map of item and count. Item is the same values in the attribute field. For example {item: "a", count: 1}. Try returning the result of apoc and you will see it.